# How to understand the inline assembler in function of " __xchg"?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, kernel

the codes is:

```
 static inline unsigned long __xchg(unsigned long x, volatile void * ptr, int size)
 {
         switch (size) {
                 case 1:
                         __asm__ __volatile__("xchgb %b0,%1"
                                 :"=q" (x)
                                 :"m" (*__xg(ptr)), "" (x)
                                 :"memory");
                         break;
                 case 2:
                         __asm__ __volatile__("xchgw %w0,%1"
                                 :"=r" (x)
                                 :"m" (*__xg(ptr)), "" (x)
                                 :"memory");
                         break;
                 case 4:
                         __asm__ __volatile__("xchgl %0,%1"
                                 :"=r" (x)
                                 :"m" (*__xg(ptr)), "" (x)
                                 :"memory");
                         break;
         }
         return x;
 }
```

What' the meaning of `"=q"`?
 And How to understand the semantic of `"" (x)`?
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`"" (x)` is more of an optimization than anything - it signals to GCC that `x` is used as a source operand, but `""` means GCC shouldn't try to place it in the instruction.

As for `"=q"`, it refers to any register whose lowest byte can be accessed (`al/bl/cl/dl` in 32-bit mode, or any register in 64-bit mode).

"+q" (x) is normally used for an operand that is updated like this.

Comment: thank you. But, I can't understand why " GCC shouldn't try to place it in the instruction"?

Comment: Since `x` is used as both a destination *and* source (because `xchg` exchanges two values), it's necessary to ensure the original value is used before being overwritten. The value is only specified once in the instruction, but acts as if it's specified twice. Again, it's a bit of an optimization hack.